# How to dissipate energy/heat in solenoid valve + flyback diode circuit

Tags: heat, flyback, solenoid-valve

A simple device that I didn't make uses solenoid valves (driven by relays) and I have to deal with the EM spikes they generate when turning off as this interferes with other equipment in my lab.  The valve manufacturer recommended a connector with MOV they sell, but it didn't help: the spike is still present, e.g. it pops in my speakers.  When I tried a flyback diode (I had a 1N4004 lying around), it quickly overheated.  I haven't found how to deal with that, as most circuits that explain this simply show a diode, or sometimes with a resistor, or a Zener to speed up the discharge.

I've calculated the energy as 0.5 * 8.15 mH * (0.45 A)^2 = 0.8 mJ, and the initial discharge power as 0.9 Ohm * (0.45 A)^2 = 0.18 W.

What is the recommended way to dissipate this energy/heat safely?  If I add a resistor, seems to me it would get the heat instead of the diode so it would be the same problem.  Is this right?  Do I need some big component(s) with heat sink?

Comment: How are you driving this solenoid? DId you put the diode the wrong way round?

Comment: What's wrong with MOV? How it  didn't help?

Comment: Driven with a relay.  Are you suggesting that this amount of energy should not overheat anything?  I paid attention, but it's not impossible.  I suppose if it was the wrong way, there would be a lot of current going through it...

Comment: @Marko The EM spike is still there.  As I understand it, the MOV still allows a very high voltage to build up, maybe too high for this circuit?

Comment: Yes, unless you are PWM modulating the thing, the diode should not even be warm. It needs to be able to briefly handle the full solenoid current though.

Comment: @Trevor Yup that was it (I had it in reverse).  Thanks!  And yes I measured the current at 0.45A and the diode is rated 1A.